# Voltage on open circuit jumping on Arduino R3

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage-level, temperature-sensor

I am working with a bunch of sensors and everything is fine so far, but I figured on analog PINS 4 & 5 the output voltage read is 0.09V higher than on 0-3... for my Sensors this is a crucial issue.

So I unplugged everything to see whats happening and found the voltage (which would supposedly be 5.0V as nothing is connected) varies, too.

```
PIN 0   PIN1   PIN2   PIN3   PIN4   PIN5
4.9365,4.8631,4.8045,4.7507,5.0000,5.0000
4.9218,4.8436,4.7752,4.7165,5.0000,5.0000
4.9120,4.8289,4.7605,4.6970,5.0000,5.0000
4.9316,4.8583,4.7898,4.7263,5.0000,5.0000
4.9462,4.8729,4.8045,4.7410,5.0000,5.0000
4.9169,4.8387,4.7654,4.7019,5.0000,5.0000
4.9022,4.8192,4.7507,4.6823,5.0000,5.0000
```

So i thought, OK, maybe my board is broken, but another one delivers similar results with NOTHING plugged in...

why is this?

All I do is `analogRead` on my PINs and multiply with `5.0/1023.0`...

I appreciate every hint.

Comment: The voltage *isn't* expected to be 5V with nothing plugged in; it's floating and like all floating inputs, is subject to noise due to its high impedance. It could be anything really, though a lot of inputs tend to float high.

Comment: Please edit question & show the code [and circuit?] that made the output

Comment: @TisteAndii ok, but why is the PIN 4 & 5 showing 5V then? Gimme a second, cannot do circuits on my phone. It is a simple voltage divider.